# Android manifest android:label inconsistent when using tools:replace

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, react-native-blob-util

I am using the lib react-native-blob-util which declares the following

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I am trying to do the following:

```
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="${appName}"
      tools:replace="android:label"
```

When the app installs, as the visible name I see the label of the library and in the app settings I see "Gradle" for the name...

Also when trying to uninstall the app, I see the following:
react-native-blob-util is part of the following app: Gradle

ps: Even when I don't use manifest placeholders and I put an harcoded string, since the value is different from the one declared in the lib, the result is a mess

Can someone explain to me why it's doing this ?

Comment: The only way I could solve my issue was to keep @string/app_name and set this variable custom thanks to react-native-config